# How can I keep the .change function from triggering by mouse wheel scrolling?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, select, scroll

In internet explorer, when you have a select, if that select is in focus (for example after right clicking it, or selecting a value from it), if you hover the mouse over the select and scroll the javascript .change function for that select triggers. The displayed option do not change though I believe the selects value does.

Is there any good way to overwrite that behaviour?

Comment: You'll have to explain a little better, what does *"hover the mouse over the select and scroll the javascript"* mean?

Comment: U have to create a handler for that, thats some deep JS u have to code & its gonna whack ur page default behaviour if not controlled its usage

Comment: It means that when you hover the mouse over the select and scroll with your mouse wheel the javascript .change function (that is I have defined a .change event for the select in javascript) triggers.